# VBScript obfuscation help in order users not to read the source code?

Tags: vbscript, obfuscation

I would like to obfuscate my vbscript and I wonder if there is a way to obfuscate the VBS script?

I want to prevent users from understanding the code.

**EdiT 1:** After obfucation I still want to run the vbscript.

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: what do you mean? do you mean to encrypt it for preventing client from accessing or seeing it? it's not logic and possible

Comment: @Rahul please check edit 1.

Comment: @FarhangAmary, Users can access the code but can not understand whats in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I used for.

```
Randomize
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fileName = Inputbox("Enter Path of the File to scramble : ")
set src = fso.OpenTextfile(fileName,1)
body = src.readall
set rep  = fso.createtextfile("Obfuscated.vbs",true)
rep.writeline "Execute(" & Obfuscate(body) & " ) "

Function Obfuscate(txt)
enc = ""
for i = 1 to len(txt)
enc = enc & "chr( " & form( asc(mid(txt,i,1)) ) & " ) & "
next
Obfuscate = enc & " vbcrlf "
End Function


Function form(n)

r = int(rnd * 10000)
k = int(rnd * 3)
if( k = 0) then ret = (r+n) & "-" & r
if( k = 1) then ret = (n-r) & "+" & r
if( k = 2) then ret = (n*r) & "/" & r
form = ret
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

See this link about hiding vbs in an exefile.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adcae113-4758-481a-a367-60d5d14d97d6/this-is-how-to-turn-vbs-and-js-files-into-exe-files-from-the-command-line-without-third-party-tools?forum=scripting